# Representing decimal numbers in Big and Little Endian?

Tags: endianness

So if I have an unsigned int which consists of 4 bytes which are stored in address 10000 to 10011. If the representation of the storage is in Big Endian, what decimal value is stored in the varuable?

ADRESS INSTRUCTION

10000:  0b01000010

10001:  137

10010:  0x13

10011:  0b11000011

So the decimal numbers are: 66, 137, 19, 195.
I thought that the Big Endian representation just is 6 613 719 195. But apparently that is wrong. So what am I missing here? If it was Little Endian it should be 1 951 913 766. But again this is wrong. So what am I missing here? Yes this is a quiz question that I got wrong and I just don't get it completely. The question is literally:

"In a high-level language a variable is declared as an unsigned int and consists of 4 bytes which are stored in the address 10000-10011. If the representation of the storage is in Big.Endian, which decimal value is stored in the variable?

ADRESS INSTRUCTION

10000:  0b01000010

10001:  137

10010:  0x13

10011:  0b11000011
"

Comment: `So the decimal numbers are: 66, 137, 19, 195. I thought that the Big Endian representation just is 6 613 719 195. But apparently that is wrong. So what am I missing here?` You're missing the fact that the number is stored in binary, not in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate bad, you need to calculate like this:

```
6631246 = 195 * 2^24 + 19 * 2^16 + 137 * 2^8 + 66
```

The representation of the value in Big Endian is to store the most significant byte (MSB) first, so the value of each byte in memory is stored in the order 10011, 10010, 10001, 10000, which is 195, 19, 137, 66 in decimal.

Comment: So the last address 10011 is seen as the MSB and the first 10000 is the LSB? And I don't really understand the calculation you've done. Can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: I looked at this video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhErugDB-34
And according to it we just represent Little.Endian as Right-To-Left and Big as Left-To-Right.

Comment: I see 66 being first, but what is 31246?